# Access violation when dynamically allocating memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am writing a program for a project at school that requires us to create a `Binary Search Tree` based on data read from a file (in this case strings). The tree should allow for duplicates by incrementing an integer value when a duplicate string is entered.

The TreeNode is a struct as follows:

```
struct TreeNode {
    string word;
    int count;
    TreeNode * left;
    TreeNode * right;
};
```

The problem I am having is when I try to call the insert function the program crashes. I run the debugger and I get the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00E2A87C in Proj12.2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000014.

What is causing this error?
Here is the rest of the relevant code:

```
TreeNode * Root = new TreeNode;
Root->right = NULL;

void insert(TreeNode *& root, string item) { //insert function, called by Root->right,temp
    if (root->word == item) {
        root->count++;
        return;
    }
    if (root == NULL && root->word != item) {
        root = new TreeNode;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        root->word = item;
        root->count = 1;
        return;
    }
    if (item < root->word) {
        insert(root->left, item);
    }
    if (item > root->word) {
        insert(root->right, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: your second if has to stay first

Comment: `root == NULL && root->word != item ` - if that first expression is true, do you *really* want to perform the second ??

Comment: @WhozCraig shouldn't short circuit kick in?

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek No, when the first condition is true there is a need to valuate the second one as well

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername, thanks. I saw that root != NULL, overwatched.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP wanted an `||` there rather than `&&`, but either are wrong (as is much of that function).

Comment: Pretty sure [**this**](http://pastebin.com/gFLKBayZ) is what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(root == NULL) should be the first check you perform before trying to access any data members using the -> operator.
condition: if(root->word == item)
condition: if (root == NULL && root->word != item)

Your root is NULL and then you are trying to access root->word which is causing the crash. You are trying to access data member using an invalid pointer.

Comment: Wow. Yep, that fixed it. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.